# How to create a Java game start screen?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, japplet

I have just finished a a game applet. Now I want to create a start screen that has a background image, and a start game button. When the user clicks the start button I want to clear the start game screen and I want the game background and all other game component to be painted to the screen. Additionally, I want the start game button to be an image that is clickable. My problem is how do you paint one screen not both in the paint() method.

How would i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on what you are doing now. I would have a panel with the start screen and close it and open a panel with the game when you click on the start button.

Answer (score 3):

I see...

- A `JPanel` acting as the primary container for the splash screen
- A `JLabel` to hold the background image
- A `JButton` for the user to click.

I also see a `CardLayout` to help make it easier to switch between your `SplashScreen` and your `Game` screen.

Check out [How to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details.

From your description, it sounds like you've started by overriding `paint` of the `JApplet` class.  Welcome to the wonderful world of *"Why you shouldn't override `paint` of a top level container"*

You need to move all you custom painting and control logic to a different component (something like a `JPanel` would do) and use it's `paintComponent` method instead.  This way, you can control where the panel goes (could be made into a stand alone application) and provide support for swappable screens/panes

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details